# How to sort this query from monday first to friday last?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to order this query and get the ticket amount for each day this week with a result like this:

```
WEEK_DAY      CREATED_TICKETS
MONDAY        3
TUESDAY       5
WEDNESDAY     0
FRIDAY        2
```

---

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CREATED_AT), 'DAY') AS WEEK_DAY,
  COUNT(ID) as CREATED_TICKETS
FROM
  FRESHDESK_API
WHERE
  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CREATED_AT), 'IW') = TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'IW')
GROUP BY
  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CREATED_AT), 'DAY')
ORDER BY
  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CREATED_AT), 'DAY') ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend:

```
select to_char(created_at, 'day') as week_day, count(*) as created_tickets
from freshdesk_api
where created_at >= trunc(sysdate, 'iw') and created_at < trunc(sysdate, 'iw') + 7
group by to_char(created_at, 'day')
order by min(created_at)
```

The trick is to use an aggregate function in the `order by` clause that applies on the `date` column.

Other changes to your query:

- I optimized the `where` clause so no date function is applied on the column being filtered; this is more efficient (one says that the predicate is *SARGable*)
- presumably something called `id` is not nullable, so `count(*)` is equivalent to `count(id)` (and more efficient, because the database does not need to `null`-check each value)
- no need to nest `trunc()` and `to_char()`; `to_char()` is sufficient here, since you only care about the day part